# How to base64url Encode Strings in Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

Is there a library function/method/class in Cocoa Touch for `base64url` encoding strings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While there isn't a standard way to do this with the Apple frameworks, you should certainly check out CocoaDev's entry and discussion on the topic: [BaseSixtyFour](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour). They have plenty of ways to work this out, and the last comment there doesn't require libcrypto, or any external frameworks (which, on iOS, is a good start). It's definitely worth a look.

**Update:** Or even better, check out [Base64 encoding options on Mac and iPhone](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) on CocoaWithLove, as it includes excellent source code.

Comment: Excellent sources, that'll do it!  Thanks.